# showing two repeaters at the same div but once at a time

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I would like to show to two different repeaters in same div but once at a time.

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
  <div class="comment1">
    <div class="comments_header"><a href="#tab1">Our Previous Comments</a></div>
      <div class="prev_comments">
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
          <asp:Repeater ID="rptcomment"  runat="server"  >
            <HeaderTemplate>
              <table style="background-color:antiquewhite;  width:600px; cellpadding="0"   >
                <tr >
                  <td colspan="2"></td>
                </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
              <tr>
                <td style="width:5px; border-bottom:dotted" >
                  <img src="../images/prople.jpg"  style="height: 77px; width: 72px" />
                </td>
                <td style=" border-bottom:dotted">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("fullname") %>' />
                  on
                  <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("datetime") %>' Font-Bold="true"/>
                  <br /> 
                  <asp:Label ID="lblcomment" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("comment") %>'/>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
              </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
          </asp:Repeater>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical" Height="457px" Width="607px"> 
          <asp:Repeater ID="RepterDetails"  runat="server"  >
            <HeaderTemplate>
              <table style="background-color:darkturquoise;  width:600px; cellpadding="0">
                <tr >
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <center> <b>Our Previous Comments</b></center>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </HeaderTemplate>
              <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width:5px; border-bottom:dotted" >
                    <img src="http://localhost:1411/images/prople.jpg"  style="height: 77px; width: 72px" />
                  </td>
                  <td style=" border-bottom:dotted">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("fullname") %>' />
                    on
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("datetime") %>' Font-Bold="true"/>
                    <br /> 
                    <asp:Label ID="lblcomment" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("comment") %>'/>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </ItemTemplate>
              <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
              </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
          </asp:Panel>
        <center>
          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" />
          <asp:HyperLink ID="linkPrev" runat="server">Previous Page</asp:HyperLink>
          <asp:HyperLink ID="linkNext" runat="server">Next Page</asp:HyperLink>
        </center>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above code when first page loads I would like to show repeater which are in `panel2` and when user clicks on link previous comment I would like to show repeater of `panel1` only but in the same div and same page.How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have each repeater inside an `asp:Panel`, this will be as easy as set the `Visible` attribute of the pertinent panel to `false`.

You can also archive this by using `CSS` styles with `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: by the way, you are going to have problems pathing your images with `http://localhost:1411`...